# Android: Create document for printing

Tags: android, html, printing, android-canvas

In my app, I have a lot of data that I need to be able to create a printable document of.

I have figured out that I can use the printing service that is included in Android 4.4 and higher. I can either create a HTML document and print that or draw on the `Canvas` of each page.

[Printing HTML Document](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs.html) or [Printing Custom Document](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html)

But my problem is, that I have a lot of content and need to format it properly. It would be a hazzle if I have to write a large HTML document as Strings... I need to both create a nice formatting and add in data from my app.

The ideal solution for me would be to make a layout file, inflate it, fill TextViews and ListViews with data and then print that view. But printing a HTML Document only allows prints from `WebView` and I have not found any way of adding a `View` or `Layout` on a `Canvas` (only the other way around, I think this is because Canvas is a layout element that can be contained in a view but not contain other layout elements).

Is there a way to print my view or it's layout?

If not, is there a way to create a HTML document that is easier than writing it out in strings? Or a way to draw all the content of a `View` to a `Canvas`?

Comment: We use http://www.cloudformatter.com/css2pdf which is a remote formatting service. Works well with Android but does require internet because the actual formatting server is in the cloud.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't help me. I don't have a web-page to print, or even a HTML document. That is my problem. If I had, I could just use print function described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is in fact a way to add all the content of a `View` to a `Canvas`. It is:

```
view.draw(canvas);
```

From [Android Developer:View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#draw(android.graphics.Canvas)):

> public void **draw** (Canvas canvas)
>
> Added in API level 1 Manually render this view (and all of its
> children) to the given Canvas. The view must have already done a full
> layout before this function is called. When implementing a view,
> implement onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) instead of overriding this
> method. If you do need to override this method, call the superclass
> version.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *canvas*  The Canvas to which the View is rendered.

This was in fact the method I was looking for all along.